# What is proper way to wire some logic for built-in models

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

`User` is built-in model.

Where to put

```
models.User.on('deleted', function(id) {
 // some logic here
})
```

`common/models/user.js` is not called for built-in `User` model.

Comment: What are you using? Is that Meteor?

Comment: @jimm101: it's [loopback](http://loopback.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the built-in models to add properties, relationships, ACLs, and other model features.  You can use the LoopBack model generator or do it programmatically.

Detailed steps are provided in the docs http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Extending+built-in+models